# Micronaut 1.0.RC1 with plain Hibernate JPA fails at startup

Tags: micronaut

when creating a blank micronaut app by using

```
mn create-app sillynaut --profile service \
   --features java,spock,jdbc-hikari,hibernate-jpa,jib
```

and then add an entity `Person`.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String surname;
    @Column
    private String firstName;

    // getter/setter omitted
}
```

When I then start the application Micronaut sucessfully instructs Hibernate to create that database table `person` but fails afterwards with the following error:

```
20:28:55.470 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: null
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: null
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1002)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.initializeContext(DefaultApplicationContext.java:190)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.readAllBeanDefinitionClasses(DefaultBeanContext.java:1912)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.start(DefaultBeanContext.java:151)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.start(DefaultApplicationContext.java:138)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:67)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:271)
    at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:257)
    at sillynaut.Application.main(Application.java:8)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: null
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1279)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.createAndRegisterSingleton(DefaultBeanContext.java:1780)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.loadContextScopeBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1466)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.initializeContext(DefaultBeanContext.java:1000)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.type.spi.TypeConfiguration.scope(TypeConfiguration.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBean.hibernateSessionFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBean.java:177)
    at io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa.$EntityManagerFactoryBean$HibernateSessionFactoryDefinition.build(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.BeanDefinitionDelegate.build(BeanDefinitionDelegate.java:197)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1263)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

To me this seems like a bug or am I missing something?

---- Please find my `build.gradle` below

```
plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.6.RELEASE"
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "4.0.0"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-eclipse" version "0.18"
    id "net.ltgt.apt-idea" version "0.18"
    id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" version "0.9.9" 
}

apply plugin:"application"
apply plugin:"java"
apply plugin:"groovy"

version "0.1"
group "sillynaut"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.micronaut:bom:1.0.0.RC1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:inject-java"
    annotationProcessor "io.micronaut:validation"
    annotationProcessor "javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2"
    implementation "io.micronaut:http-client"
    compile "io.micronaut:inject"
    implementation "io.micronaut:validation"
    implementation "io.micronaut:runtime"
    implementation "io.micronaut.configuration:jdbc-hikari"
    implementation "io.micronaut.configuration:hibernate-jpa"
    implementation "io.micronaut:http-server-netty"
    implementation "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2"
    compileOnly "io.micronaut:inject-java"
    runtimeOnly "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3"
    runtimeOnly "io.micronaut.configuration:jdbc-tomcat"
    testImplementation("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.2-groovy-2.4") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy", module: "groovy-all"
    }
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:inject-groovy"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
    testImplementation "io.micronaut:inject-java"
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"

    runtime 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:2.2.5'
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

run.jvmArgs('-noverify', '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1')

mainClassName = "sillynaut.Application"
compileJava.options.compilerArgs += '-parameters'
compileTestJava.options.compilerArgs += '-parameters'
jib.to.image = 'gcr.io/sillynaut/jib-image'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you have both `jdbc-tomcat` and `jdbc-hikari` on the runtime classpath. That is causing 2 data sources to be created with the same name qualifier. This is a bug in the CLI that caused the project to be created this way

I've filed an issue for you https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/681